# C++ read from istream until newline (but not whitespace)

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a std::istream which refers to matrix data, something like:

```
0.0 1.0 2.0
3.0 4.0 5.0
```

Now, in order to assess the number of columns I would like to have some code like:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
double x;
while( (...something...) && (istream >> x) )
{
    vec.push_back(x); 
}
//Here vec should contain 0.0, 1.0 and 2.0
```

where the ...something... part evaluates to false after I read 2.0 and istream at the point should be at 3.0 so that the next

```
istream >> x;
```

should set x equal to 3.0.

How would you achieve this result? I guess that the while condition

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason I would like to pursue this approach (if doable) is to avoid creating temporary objects (apart from the double x). The matrix is then created by std::swap - ing the vector above with the matrix internal storage (it is implemented via a std::vector).

Comment: well, you can do it with a temporary in 10 simple lines, or you can do it without the temporary in 50 hard lines.  Use a temporary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) method to check the next character:

```
while ((istream.peek()!='\n') && (istream>>x))
```

Comment: This is easily broken if the line contains *any* white-space before the <newline>

Comment: True; there's no error-checking at all here, I'm just assuming the input is well-formed.

Answer (score 12):

Read the lines into a std::string using [std::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), then assign the string to a [std::istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) object, and extract the data from that rather than directly from istream.

Comment: Sorry I did not make this clear but this is what I am trying to avoid. Point is I do not know in advance if the matrix is going to have many cols or many rows and having string store 10.000 doubles is not a very efficient approch to the problem :) Sorry again for not making this clear, my fault.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<double> vec;
{
   std::string line;
   std::getline( ifile, line );
   std::istringstream is(line);
   std::copy( std::istream_iterator<double>(is), std::istream_iterator<double>(),
              std::back_inserter(vec) );
}
std::cout << "Input has " << vec.size() << " columns." << std::endl;
std::cout << "Read values are: ";
std::copy( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
           std::ostream_iterator<double>( std::cout, " " ) );
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: OP specifically mentioned not wanting to buffer a whole line first.

Comment: His proposed code requests that after the while the vector should contain the first line: `//Here vec should contain 0.0, 1.0 and 2.0`. Does he not want to read a line or the whole file?

Comment: Yes I want to end the while loop after the first line has been read (and keep the rest in istream for further reading) but I would like to avoid having to create a string to store the first whole line before putting it in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::istream::peek()` to check if the next character is a newline.
See [this entry](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/peek/) in the cplusplus.com reference.

Answer (score 0):

Read the number, then read one character to see if it's newline.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem
Input is as below:

```
1 2
3 4 5
```

The 1st two were N1 and N2
Then there is a newline
then elements 3 4 5, i dont know how many these will be.

```
// read N1 & N2 using cin
int N1, N2;
cin >> N1;
cin >> N2;

// skip the new line which is after N2 (i.e; 2 value in 1st line)
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

// now read 3 4 5 elements
int ele;
// 2nd EOF condition may required,
//    depending on if you dont have last new-line, and it is end of file.
while ((cin_.peek() != '\n') && (cin_.peek() != EOF)) {
  cin >> ele;
  // do something with ele
}
```

This worked perfect for me.